# Unuseful backup

Tags: wallet, wallet-recovery, backup

I know `wallet.dat` needs to do back up every time after I am going a transaction, 'because the backup will become unuseful.

After what else cases do I need to do backup again? What cases do my last backup `wallet.dat` unuseful?

Comment: If your wallet was created by Bitcoin Core 0.13 or later, this is not the case. Such wallets store a deterministic seed from which all future keys are generated.

Comment: @PieterWuille My wallet was created in BC v. 0.21. Do you want to say I don't need backup to?

Comment: He say that you have to do it only once. If you have saved the seed (that's inside the wallet.dat file), all addresses can be calculated from that one, so you don't need to back up every new address, just once after you created the wallet.